# React router 6+ : how to strongly type the params option in route loader?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-typescript

Have router

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/todos/:todoId',
    element: <Todo />,
    loader: todoLoader,
  }
]);
```

Have loader

```js
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }) => {
  return await fetchData(params.todoId);
};
```

How to type params according to path?

Waiting for the highlighting of the specified parameters in the path.

UPDATE:
Thanks @DrewReese @LindaPaiste came to the following solution.

```js
const PathNames = {
  todoDetail: '/todos/:idTodo',
} as const;

interface Args extends ActionFunctionArgs {
  params: Params<ParamParseKey<typeof PathNames.todoDetail>>;
}

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }:Args) => {
  return await fetchData(params.todoId);
};
```

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese @LindaPaiste came to the following solution.

```lang-js

const PathNames = { 
  todoDetail: '/todos/:idTodo' 
} as const;

interface Args extends ActionFunctionArgs {
  params: Params<ParamParseKey<typeof PathNames.todoDetail>>;
}

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }: Args) => {
  return await fetchData(params.todoId);
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Primary Approach

> ```
> declare type _PathParam<Path extends string> = Path extends `${infer L}/${infer R}` ? _PathParam<L> | _PathParam<R> : Path extends `:${infer Param}` ? Param extends `${infer Optional}?` ? Optional : Param : never;
> /**
>  * Examples:
>  * "/a/b/*" -> "*"
>  * ":a" -> "a"
>  * "/a/:b" -> "b"
>  * "/a/blahblahblah:b" -> "b"
>  * "/:a/:b" -> "a" | "b" 
>  * "/:a/b/:c/*" -> "a" | "c" | "*"
>  */
> declare type PathParam<Path extends string> = Path extends "*" ? "*" : Path extends `${infer Rest}/*` ? "*" | _PathParam<Rest> : _PathParam<Path>;
> export declare type ParamParseKey<Segment extends string> = [
>     PathParam<Segment>
> ] extends [never] ? string : PathParam<Segment>;
> /**
>  * The parameters that were parsed from the URL path.
>  */
> export declare type Params<Key extends string = string> = {
>     readonly [key in Key]: string | undefined;
> };
> ```

Declare a map/object of paths (key - value) that you can use RRD's `Params` and `ParamParseKey` utility types to extract the route path parameters (*Credit to LindaPaiste and Qvazi for method*).

```js
const Paths = {
  todoDetail: "/todos/:idTodo",
} as const;

interface TodoLoaderArgs extends ActionFunctionArgs {
  params: Params<ParamParseKey<typeof Paths.todoDetail>>;
}

const todoLoader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }: TodoLoaderArgs) => {
  return await fetchData(params.idTodo);
};
```

[image]

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: Paths.todoDetail,
    element: <Todo />,
    loader: todoLoader as LoaderFunction
  },
]);
```

However, the `fetchData` function expects a `string` type, so there's an incompatibility here since `params.idTodo` is typed as `string | undefined`. It's fixed by doing a conditional check before accessing

```js
const todoLoader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }: TodoLoaderArgs) => {
  return params.idTodo ? await fetchData(params.idTodo) : null;
};
```

or asserting it's non-null, e.g. `fetchData(params.idTodo!)` or you can provide a fallback, e.g. `fetchData(params.idTodo ?? "")`. Perhaps the fallback can be some default query parameter value for the data fetching.

```js
const todoLoader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }: TodoLoaderArgs) => {
  return await fetchData(params.idTodo ?? "");
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-6-how-to-strongly-type-the-params-option-in-route-loader (forked)]

## Secondary Approach

It's a bit of a roundabout method, but this appears to be correctly typed and working in a running codesandbox, might be a bit "hackish" though (*my Typescript foo is not great*). The gist is that you need to override the loader function `args` parameter so you can override the `params` property to include the path params you want to access in the loader.

The loader definitions to override:

> ```
> /**
>  * The parameters that were parsed from the URL path.
>  */
> export declare type Params<Key extends string = string> = {
>     readonly [key in Key]: string | undefined;
> };
>
> /**
>  * @private
>  * Arguments passed to route loader/action functions.  Same for now but we keep
>  * this as a private implementation detail in case they diverge in the future.
>  */
> interface DataFunctionArgs {
>     request: Request;
>     params: Params;
>     context?: any;
> }
> /**
>  * Arguments passed to loader functions
>  */
> export interface LoaderFunctionArgs extends DataFunctionArgs {
> }
> /**
>  * Route loader function signature
>  */
> export interface LoaderFunction {
>     (args: LoaderFunctionArgs): Promise<Response> | Response | Promise<any> | any;
> }
> ```

New interface declarations and usage:

```
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
  Navigate,
  useLoaderData,
  LoaderFunction,
  LoaderFunctionArgs
} from "react-router-dom";

interface TodoLoaderFunctionArgs extends Omit<LoaderFunctionArgs, "params"> {
  params: {
    todoId: string;
  };
}

interface TodoLoaderFunction extends Omit<LoaderFunction, "args"> {
  (args: TodoLoaderFunctionArgs):
    | Promise<Response>
    | Response
    | Promise<any>
    | any;
}

const todoLoader: TodoLoaderFunction = async ({ params }) => {
  return await fetchData(params.todoId);
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/todos/:todoId",
    element: <Todo />,
    loader: todoLoader as LoaderFunction
  },
]);
```

[image]

[image: Edit react-router-6-how-to-strongly-type-the-params-option-in-route-loader]

## Secondary Approach #2

An alternative, which might be a little simpler, would be to simply recast the `params` prop.

```js
interface Params {
  todoId: string
}

const todoLoader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }) => {
  const typedParams = params as unknown as Params;
  return await fetchData(typedParams.todoId);
};
```

[image]

Comment: If I have to change the path string, then I will have to change the params interface manually =) I thought there was a best practice for this. Looks like we'll have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @qvazi Yes, that you need to do if you change the route path. It's a tradeoff it seems.

Comment: I remember playing with this once and using some crazy TS stuff to infer the keys of the params using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

Comment: [Here's what I just came up with](https://tsplay.dev/WG4yMw) but then I realized that react-router [has some of these types](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/0ce0e4c728129efe214521a22fb902fa652bac70/packages/router/utils.ts#L196-L233) already.

Comment: @LindaPaiste
Thank you. I imported Params, ParamParseKey and made the path a constant. Now there is only one source of truth =)  

`const PathNames = {
  todoDetail: '/todos/:idTodo',
} as const;

interface Args extends ActionFunctionArgs {
  params: Params<ParamParseKey<typeof PathNames.todoDetail>>;
}`

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I wonder why there is neither a simpler syntax for this common task, nor official typescript tutorial from react-router developers.

Answer (score 7):

Simpler, something like this worked for me:

```
import type { Params } from "react-router-dom";
export async function loader({ params }: { params: Params<"todoId"> }) {
  return await fetchData(params.todoId);
};
```

If you have more than one parameter, the generic parameter is a union such as `"todoId" | "userId"`.